# Connecting python to league of legends chat through xmpp

Tags: python, r, xmpp, chat, xmpppy

I am trying to connect python to my league of legends chat (brazilian server) interface to try to run some automatic responses to pings and etc. But I'm not finding success. This is the code I'm running in python Python 3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 10:41:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32. I'm using my username and password in my code.

```
import xmpp

conn = xmpp.Client("pvp.net")
if not conn.connect(server=("br.chat.si.riotgames.com", 5223)):
    print ("connect failed.")
    exit()

if not conn.auth("USER", "AIR_" + "PASSWORD", "xiff"):
    print ("auth failed.")
    exit()
```

And these are the errors I'm getting

```
>   Invalid debugflag given: always Invalid debugflag given: nodebuilder
> DEBUG:  DEBUG: Debug created for
> C:\Users\caioh\PycharmProjects\ProjectBadBot\venv\lib\site-packages\xmpppy-0.6.1-py3.7.egg\xmpp\client.py
> DEBUG:  flags defined: always,nodebuilder DEBUG: socket       start
> Plugging <xmpp.transports.TCPsocket object at 0x000002529F9F0DC8> into
> <xmpp.client.Client object at 0x000002529F8DD3C8> DEBUG: socket      
> warn  Could not load one of the supported DNS libraries (dnspython or
> pydns). SRV records will not be queried and you may need to set custom
> hostname/port for some servers to be accessible.\n DEBUG: socket      
> start Successfully connected to remote host
> ('br.chat.si.riotgames.com', 5223) DEBUG: tls          start Plugging
> <xmpp.transports.TLS object at 0x000002529FDCB248> into
> <xmpp.client.Client object at 0x000002529F8DD3C8> DEBUG: dispatcher  
> start Plugging <xmpp.dispatcher.Dispatcher object at
> 0x000002529FDE1948> into <xmpp.client.Client object at
> 0x000002529F8DD3C8> DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering namespace
> "unknown" DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "unknown" as
> <class 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(unknown) DEBUG: dispatcher   info 
> Registering protocol "default" as <class
> 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(unknown) DEBUG: dispatcher   info 
> Registering namespace "http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" DEBUG:
> dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "unknown" as <class
> 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(http://etherx.jabber.org/streams) DEBUG:
> dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "default" as <class
> 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(http://etherx.jabber.org/streams) DEBUG:
> dispatcher   info  Registering namespace "jabber:client" DEBUG:
> dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "unknown" as <class
> 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(jabber:client) DEBUG: dispatcher   info 
> Registering protocol "default" as <class
> 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(jabber:client) DEBUG: dispatcher   info 
> Registering protocol "iq" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Iq'>(jabber:client)
> DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "presence" as <class
> 'xmpp.protocol.Presence'>(jabber:client) DEBUG: dispatcher   info 
> Registering protocol "message" as <class
> 'xmpp.protocol.Message'>(jabber:client) DEBUG: dispatcher   info 
> Registering handler <bound method Dispatcher.streamErrorHandler of
> <xmpp.dispatcher.Dispatcher object at 0x000002529FDE1948>> for "error"
> type-> ns->(http://etherx.jabber.org/streams) DEBUG: dispatcher   warn
> Registering protocol "error" as <class
> 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(http://etherx.jabber.org/streams) DEBUG:
> socket       sent  <?xml version='1.0'?>   <stream:stream
> xmlns="jabber:client" version="1.0"
> xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" to="pvp.net" > DEBUG:
> socket       warn  SSL_WANT_READ while receiving data, asking for a
> retry DEBUG: socket       got   <?xml version='1.0'?>   <stream:stream
> xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'
> id='1475788316' from='br1.pvp.net'>   <stream:error>   <host-unknown
> xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/>   </stream:error>  
> </stream:stream> DEBUG: dispatcher   ok    Got
> http://etherx.jabber.org/streams/error stanza DEBUG: dispatcher   ok  
> Dispatching error stanza with type->
> props->['urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'] id->None Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/caioh/PycharmProjects/ProjectBadBot/test,py", line 4, in
> <module>
>     if not conn.connect(server=("br.chat.si.riotgames.com", 5223)):   File
> "C:\Users\caioh\PycharmProjects\ProjectBadBot\venv\lib\site-packages\xmpppy-0.6.1-py3.7.egg\xmpp\client.py",
> line 203, in connect   File
> "C:\Users\caioh\PycharmProjects\ProjectBadBot\venv\lib\site-packages\xmpppy-0.6.1-py3.7.egg\xmpp\client.py",
> line 187, in connect   File
> "C:\Users\caioh\PycharmProjects\ProjectBadBot\venv\lib\site-packages\xmpppy-0.6.1-py3.7.egg\xmpp\dispatcher.py",
> line 126, in Process   File
> "C:\Users\caioh\PycharmProjects\ProjectBadBot\venv\lib\site-packages\xmpppy-0.6.1-py3.7.egg\xmpp\dispatcher.py",
> line 304, in dispatch   File
> "C:\Users\caioh\PycharmProjects\ProjectBadBot\venv\lib\site-packages\xmpppy-0.6.1-py3.7.egg\xmpp\dispatcher.py",
> line 216, in streamErrorHandler xmpp.protocol.HostUnknown:
> ('host-unknown', '')
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm fairly new to python and I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do this, maybe trying to connect directly through the client? I'm more familiar with R, is there an easir way to do it in it?